# Managing a CI/CD Pipeline from another Pipeline - Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline(Say A). In it, I have written a PowerShell script which helps me to update a particular package in the solution. After merging the changed code with the master branch using this PowerShell script, it automatically triggers another pipeline(say B) whose triggering depends on the changes in master. I have to control the triggering of this pipeline B from Pipeline A - like get the status of the triggered pipeline B, disable the trigger of pipeline B from A, etc. Please help me with this scenario.

Comment: how do you trigger B?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk : B depends on the master branch changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a powershell task to call [build rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the status of another pipeline(ie. Pipeline B).

First to get the latest build of Pipeline B, you can use below rest api.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&$top={$top}&api-version=5.1`

Below is the inline script example in the powershell task to get the build status.

```
$uri = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionId}&`$top=1&api-version=5.1"
 
$result =Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

$status = $result.value[0].status
```

`$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` is the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with which you can refer to the access token directly in the scripts.

To cancel pipeline B in pipeline A you can call [update Build rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). See below example. First get the build from above api, then update the `status` to `cancelling`

```
$build = $result.value[0] 
$uriupdate = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$($build.id)?api-version=5.1"

$build.status = "cancelling"

$body = $build | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$update = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriupdate -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json"  -Method patch -Body $body
```

To skip a build when pushing the changes, you can just include `[skip ci]` in the commit message as Shamrai mentioned.

`git commit -m message [skip ci]`

Answer (score 1):

> I have to control the triggering of this pipeline B from Pipeline A -
> like get the status of the triggered pipeline B, disable the trigger
> of pipeline B from A, etc.

1. You can use REST API with PowerShell to control your builds: [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).
2. To disable the trigger, add `scip ci` into your commit message: [Skipping CI for individual commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits)

Comment: Thanks. I am accepting @Levi' s Solution since it is more elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use output variable in powershell task. And based on that you can control the next job to execute. This way you don't have to use multiple build pipelines instead multiple jobs in a single pipeline.

You can refer the Microsoft document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)